# in_array check for non false values

Tags: php

```
$array = array(
    'vegs' => 'tomatos',
    'cheese' => false,
    'nuts' => 765,
    '' => null,
    'fruits' => 'apples'
);

var_dump(in_array(false, $array, true)); //returns true because there is a false value
```

How to check strictly if there is at least one NON-false (string, true, int) value in array using in_array only or anything but not foreach?

```
var_dump(in_array(!false, $array, true)); //this checks only for boolean true values

var_dump(!in_array(false, $array, true)); //this returns true when all values are non-false
```

Comment: Why restrict yourself to in_array() only; this is a perfect use for array_reduce()

Comment: anything but not foreach

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Actual solution below**

Just put the negation at the right position:

```
var_dump(!in_array(false, $array, true));
```

Of course this will also be true if the array contains no elements at all, so what you want is:

```
var_dump(!in_array(false, $array, true) && count($array));
```

***Edit:*** forget it, that was the answer for "array contains *only* values that are not exactly false", not "array contains *at least one* value that is not exactly false"

**Actual solution:**

```
var_dump(
  0 < count(array_filter($array, function($value) { return $value !== false; }))
);
```

`array_filter` returns an array with all values that are `!== false`, if it is not empty, your condition is true.

Or simplified as suggested in the comments:

```
var_dump(
  (bool) array_filter($array, function($value) { return $value !== false; })
);
```

Of course, the cast to `bool` also can be omitted if used in an `if` clause.

Comment: to be more explicit I edited: "How to check strictly if there is at least one NON-false (string, true, int) value in array". So with !in_array(false, $array, true) - this is impossible.

Comment: this returns true when all values are non-false

Comment: I have no way to test it, but would `in_array(true, $array, true)` do the job? Does it check for any 'non-false' value when evaluating true, or does it need to be necessarily `true` boolean?

Comment: StuckAtWork: in_array(true, $array, true) checks only for boolean true, I need all non-false: boolean true, int, float, string

Comment: fab: thanks for the idea with array_filter, but I think more elegant would be to use this: if (array_filter($array)) {...} - that means if $array has at least one non-false value

Comment: That's right, you can leave out `count` because an empty array will be casted to false if you use it as boolean.

Comment: fab: can you edit your answer? (if (array_filter($array)) {...}) I will vote it :)

Comment: fab: I think you can remove the callback function as well "function($value) { return $value !== false; }"

Comment: from doc: If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed.

Comment: No, if you remove the callback function, only a **non-strict** comparison with `false` occurs.

Answer (score 0):

> How to check strictly if there is at least one NON-false (string,
>   true, int) value in array using in_array only or anything but not
>   foreach?

This is not possible because:

- String: this data type can contain any value, its not like boolean (true or false) or NULL.
- INT: same as string, how to check for unknown?
- Boolean: possible.
- NULL: possible.

Then, INT and STRING data types can't be found just using an abstract (int) or (string)!

EDIT:

```
function get_type($v)
{
    return(gettype($v));
}

$types = array_map("get_type", $array);

print_r($types);
```

RESULT:

```
Array
(
    [vegs] => string
    [cheese] => boolean
    [nuts] => integer
    [] => NULL
    [fruits] => string
)
```

Comment: It's not possible with `in_array`, right. But that was not the whole question.